# Mostrar imagen de GridView a una img de una tabla asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web

Quiero pasar una imagen de un `GridView` a una tabla que tiene la etiqueta **IMG**.

Yo anteriormente estaba pasando datos de `DataGridView` a un `TexBox` y me resultó. Ahora el problema es que no se puede mostrar en esa etiqueta.

Este es el código que utilizo para pasar datos:

```
protected void DtgSolicitudes_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        try
        {
            DtSet = new DataSet();        
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ObtenerCadenaConexion());
            con.Open();
            DtgSolicitudes.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow row = DtgSolicitudes.SelectedRow;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_BuscarSeguimiento", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("OPT", 2);
            SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("periodo", "");
            SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("oficina", "");
            SqlParameter p4 = new SqlParameter("rubro", row.Cells[3].Text);

            cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p3);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p4);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Text);
            TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Text);
            TextBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[3].Text);
            TextBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[4].Text);
            TextBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[5].Text);
            TextBox6.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[6].Text);
            TextBox7.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[7].Text);
            TextBox8.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[8].Text);
            TextBox9.Text = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[9].Text);

            Image1.ImageUrl = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[12].Text);
            var imagen = row.FindControl("img") as Image;

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            // DvError.Visible = true;
            Session["13"] = Ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

**SQL SERVER MI TABLA**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me sale en blanco la imagen con ese nombre `byte`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: datagridview? en un entorno web no existe este componente, no sera que usas el GridView ?

Comment: si disculpen era gridview

Comment: @LeandroTuttini he colocado la imagen donde me recupera la imagen y lo pone como system.byte[]

Comment: el campo filecontent de que tipo lo defines ? es un image o varbinary

Comment: como img en sql server

Comment: ok, entonces aplica perfecto el articulo, si analizas el EmpleadosDAL.ObtenerById() podrias ver como se recupera la entidad dentro del handler, para asi enviarla con el Response.BinaryWrite

Comment: @LeandroTuttini yo anteriormente en una pagina lo mostraba distino pero  lo hago lo mismo si tendras tu correo para enviarte me ayudes por favor

Comment: Es que hay dos alternativas, o generas el archivo fisico, temporal y unes el img de html a este o lo generas en runtime como explico en el articulo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56398/discussion-between-pierro-and-leandro-tuttini).

Comment: @LeandroTuttini no puedo descargar el codigo sale este codigo no se puede abrir en este momento –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que la imagen bit lo conviertas en una img tienes que declarar el siguiente script:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListImagenes" runat="server" Visible="true">
                                              <ItemTemplate>
                                             <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("filecontent"))  %>' runat="server" Style="width: 150px; height: 150px" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" />

                                                                              <script>
                                                                                  $(document).ready(function () {

                                                                                      $('<%#  "#ListImagenes_Image1_" + Container.DisplayIndex %>').popover({
                                                                                          html: true,
                                                                                          trigger: 'hover',
                                                                                          content: '<img src="' + '<%# "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("filecontent")) %>' + '" id="popover_img" Style="width: 500px" />'
                                                                                      }).hover(function () {
                                                                                          $('#popover_img').attr('src', $(this).data('img'));
                                                                                      });

                                                                                      $('<%#  "#ListImagenes_Image1_" + Container.DisplayIndex %>').mouseover(function () {
                                                                                          $('<%#  "#ListImagenes_Image1_" + Container.DisplayIndex %>').popover('show')
                                            });

                                                                                      $('<%#  "#ListImagenes_Image1_" + Container.DisplayIndex %>').mouseout(function () {
                                                                                          $('<%#  "#ListImagenes_Image1_" + Container.DisplayIndex %>').popover('hide')
                                            });
                                                                                  });
```

Answer (score 1):

En un entorno web si la imagen estaá persistida en la base de datos como `array` de `byte` deberías recuperarla de forma indirecta por medio de un *handler* que envíe en el `Response` la imagen para mostrarla en el tag `img`

En el artículo

[[ASP.NET] GridView – Edición Empleados](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2011/05/aspnet-gridview-edicion-empleados.html)

[Descarga codigo ejemplo](https://onedrive.live.com/?id=5C82AA0C9BBAF5B3%21538&cid=5C82AA0C9BBAF5B3)

explico como podrias lograrlo.

La columna que muestra la imagen debería ser:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Imagen">
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
                       ImageUrl='<%# Eval("IdEmpleado", "imagen.ashx?id={0}") %>' Width="100px" Height="100px" />
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

En donde la `ImageUrl` apunta al *handler* para que este por medio del `id` de la entidad devuelva el `array` de `byte` en el `Response`.

Comment: me sale como la imagen byte

Comment: @Pierro, busca cómo convertir ese valor en una imagen. **No se cual sea la mejor manera**, pero creo que con este valor, conviertes este valor en un archivo físico, luego tomas la ruta del archivo en donde lo creaste y en la propiedad `ImageUrl` colocas la ruta completa de la imagen generada.

Comment: Es que no se convierte ningun valor en imagen ni tampoco es encesario un archivo fisico. La ides es relaciona el tag de image con el handler para obtner la imagen directamente en runtime, sin intermedios

Comment: @LeandroTuttini no puedo descargar el codigo sale este codigo no se puede abrir en este momento

Comment: pero estas accediendo al link que deje en la respuesta? es el mismo que deberia estar en el articulo del blog, pero debo actualizarlo